# Alguien sabe porque me aparcen las variables que defino en VUE.js de esta forma

Tags: php, vue.js

al recargar mi aplicación me salen la variables como lo indica la imagen {{variable}}, y despues me sale la información normal, a mi parecer se mira feo es normal eso? gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, no es normal, pero sin ver código no podemos ayudar mucho.

Comment: Puedes evitar que se muestre el dom de vue utilizando `v-cloak` como se indica en la documentación: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

Answer (score 1):

Para corregir ese detalle debes hacer uso de la propiedad v-text; vas a hacer el acomodo de tu código de la siguiente manera

Este es el acomodo original que se hace, sin embargo se presenta el problema de que por unos segundos se ve la sintáxis de las dobles llaves

**EJEMPLO(Te mostraré como hacerlo mediante un ejemplo para que solo lo adaptes a tus necesidades)**

```
<ul v-for="a in heros">
   <li>{{ a.name }}</li>
   <li>{{ a.poder }}</li>
   <li>{{ a.nivel }}</li>
 </ul>
```

Debes ahora hacer uso de la directiva v-text, cambiando tu código de la siguiente manera

```
<ul v-for="a in heros">
   <li v-text="a.name"></li>
   <li v-text="a.poder"></li>
   <li v-text="a.nivel"></li>
 </ul>
```

> Como puedes notar gracias a la directiva v-text los valores se cargan
>   inmediantamente con el elemento del DOM por lo cual ese error de
>   presnetación que mencionas desaparecerá

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que se muestren la llaves te puedes apoyar en `v-cloak` junto con css, como se indica en la documentación de Vue.

Declaramos la regla css:

```
[v-cloak] { display: none }
```

Y en el elemento de nuestra instancia de Vue añadimos la directiva `v-cloak

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Esto lo que hará es que se oculte el contenido hasta que la instancia de Vue este lista.

Documentación: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak